# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToast.SHORT') - React Native iOS Version index.bundle

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

With my React Native project that I started with

```
react-native init PROJECTNAME  (NOT EXPO)
```

I finished the app and the Android version works properly.  When I started the project, the iOS version works properly too.  However after coding and coding for Android....when I completed the Android version and it works properly, now then I run the iOS version it gave me a few errors....mostly with having to install RNPermission, etc.

After solving those issues, I am now facing this new error that I don't know how to solve:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToast.SHORT')
```

It would seem like this problem happens in the index.bundle.

How to solve?

Comment: Are you using any library to show toast in your app?

Comment: I did not intentionally add any library for usings Toasts and I also have not used Toast directly.  However I'm using React Native so I don't know if the system automatically uses Toasts or not....

Comment: I'm facing this issue, I removed the Toast message completely, but still facing this issue. Do you have a fix for this?